# Module does not display custom settings, magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <ronisbt translate="label" module="feedback">
            <label>Feedback</label>
            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
        </ronisbt>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <feedback_setting module="feedback" translate="label">
            <label>Feedback</label>
            <tab>Feedback</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <captcha translate="label">
                    <label>Captcha</label>
                    <expanded>1</expanded>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_Website>1</show_in_Website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <blocks_captcha_secret>
                            <label>Secret key</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_Website>1</show_in_Website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </blocks_captcha_secret>
                        <blocks_captcha_public>
                            <label>Public key</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_Website>1</show_in_Website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </blocks_captcha_public>
                    </fields>
                </captcha>
            </groups>
        </feedback_setting>
    </sections>
</config>
```

adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <feedback_setting translation="title" module="feedback">
                                        <title>Feedback</title>
                                    </feedback_setting>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
<menu>
    <cms>
        <children>
            <feedback translate="title" module="feedback">
                <title>Contact Form</title>
                <action>adminhtml/ronisfb</action>
                <sort_order>20</sort_order>
            </feedback>
        </children>
    </cms>
</menu>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<tab>Feedback</tab>
```

to

```
<tab>ronisbt</tab>
```

Now looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <ronisbt translate="label" module="feedback">
            <label>Feedback</label>
            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
        </ronisbt>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <feedback_setting module="feedback" translate="label">
            <label>Feedback</label>
            <tab>ronisbt</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <captcha translate="label">
                    <label>Captcha</label>
                    <expanded>1</expanded>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_Website>1</show_in_Website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <blocks_captcha_secret>
                            <label>Secret key</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_Website>1</show_in_Website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </blocks_captcha_secret>
                        <blocks_captcha_public>
                            <label>Public key</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_Website>1</show_in_Website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </blocks_captcha_public>
                    </fields>
                </captcha>
            </groups>
        </feedback_setting>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Clear cache.